# TextBlock hosted inside StackPanel/Grid won't Wrap

Tags: wpf

How do I make `TexBox` with an extremely long text wrap when it's placed inside `StackPanel`/`Grid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StackPanel stretches accordingly to the size of its content. So if you use Grid and with TextWrapping you can achieve the desired result

```
<Grid>
        <TextBlock  
            TextWrapping="Wrap"
            Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus leo lectus, viverra ut lobortis vel, mollis eget lectus. Suspendisse laoreet consequat ultrices. Curabitur ultricies, tortor feugiat porttitor faucibus, lorem eros pretium nisl, eu ullamcorper mauris tortor sit amet augue." />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 4):

In the TextBox control (XAML), put:

```
TextWrapping="Wrap"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put TextBox inside to StackPanel/Grid like this:

Stackpanel:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TexBox TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <TexBox TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</Grid>
```

If you set TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow", it will hide everything that goes over it's height. In other words, height won't automatically change by its content.